# how to send a parameter from html to django view.py

Tags: python, html, django

I am a beginner and did a lot of search but every time I got only "django to html" as search result every time. I am following this tutorial:

http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html

but on the way I am not able to pass paramter from html to view.py.

Here is my directory:

[image]

directory: mysite:

[image]

directory: books

[image]

directory: templates

[image]

**search_form.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/search/" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="q">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
def search_form(request):
    return render(request, 'books/search_form.html')

def search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        message = 'You searched for: %r' % request.GET['q']
    else:
        message = 'You submitted an empty form.'
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

**urls.py** for books

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.search_form,name='search_form'),
               url(r'^$', views.search,name='search'),

]
```

and urls.py in mysite directory

```
"""mysite URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Add an import:  from blog import urls as blog_urls
    2. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    3. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include(blog_urls))
"""
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^books/', include('books.urls')),
]
```

Now the problem is when I type: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/books/`
it successfully shows the form's textbox and submit button but when I press **submit** it shows me this:

[image]

Comment: You did not define the URL in `urls.py`.

Comment: change your form action to be `<form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="get">` and never use hardcoded urls in templates. Also i'd suggest to start using class based views

Comment: it did remove the error but nothing is printing such as in view i have place :
"You searched for: %r'" which shd be printing such thing

Comment: Klaus did u mean i shd declare something in mysite urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need two different regexes for the `search_form` and `search` results. For example:

```
url(r'^$',views.search_form,name='search_form'),
url(r'^search/$', views.search,name='search'),
```

Next, you need to update the form's action to point to the search view. Since you have included your `books/urls.py` with the `/books/` prefix, you need:

```
<form action="/books/search/" method="get">
```

It is better to use the url tag instead of hardcoding your urls. In this case, you would do:

```
<form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="get">
```

Comment: Absolutely correct. Thnx bro. but tell me how to use url tag? instead of hardcoding

Comment: I showed you how to use the url tag already - `{% url 'search' %}`. There's more info about it [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Comment: one thing more why i m getting "u" in the output string: "You searched for: u'java'"

Comment: Because you used `%r` instead of `%s`.

Comment: oh just like C. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of Alasdair I would use "books:search" for clear namespace:

```
<form action="{% url 'books:search' %}" method="get">
```

Comment: u'books' is not a registered namespace

Comment: If you do this, you also have to include the namespace in the url config, i.e. `url(r'^books/', include('books.urls', namespace='books')),`

Answer (score 0):

The url /search/ doesn't exist, you didnt define that it should exist.

It would be /books/ judging from that URLs file you showed.  Also on a side note, don't use http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html

They have a warning on the main page that it is no longer up to date.

Use masteringdjango.com and other up to date resources.